# Getting key instead of value from .resx file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've an error handler class and when I am trying to display exception message, I can't take the value from .resx file. Doesn't matter what I write in ErrorResources.resx file, I'll get the key.

```
 public class ErrorHandler
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
     public ErrorHandler(RequestDelegate next)
     {
         this._next = next;
     }

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger<ErrorHandler> logger, IStringLocalizer<ErrorResources> localizer)
     {
         try
         {
             await _next(context);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             await HandleAsync(context, ex, logger, localizer);
         }
     }

     private static Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, ILogger<ErrorHandler> logger, IStringLocalizer<ErrorResources> localizer)
     {
         var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
         var errorMessageKey = "InternalServerError";

         var message = localizer[errorMessageKey].ToString();

         switch (ex)
         {
             case Application.CustomExceptions.PersonNotFoundException:
                 statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                 errorMessageKey = "PersonNotFound";
                 message = localizer[errorMessageKey].ToString(); //HERE I AM GETTING PersonNotFound
                 break;
            //rest of the code
         }

     }
 }
```

This is localizer :

```
 public class Localizer
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

     public Localizer(RequestDelegate next)
     {
         _next = next;
     }

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
     {
         var userLanguage = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString().Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
         var culture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLanguage) ? "en-US" : userLanguage;

         var defaultLanguage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLanguage) ? "en-US" : userLanguage;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultLanguage))
         {
             try
             {
                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(defaultLanguage);
                 CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(defaultLanguage);
             }
             catch (CultureNotFoundException)
             {
             }
         }
         await _next(context);
     }
 

    }
```

Part of Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<ErrorResources>>();
```

This is the folder and files [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try follow these steps:

1,Remove this line:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<ErrorResources>>();
```

You don't need to register `IStringLocalizer` yourself,it has already been registered with

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization()
```

2,Create a class named of `ErrorResources` in your project's root directory

3,Add key-value pairs in your `ErrorResources.resx` :

A minimal sample:

[image]

[image]

When I debug,it's ok:

[image]